# Forgot Password asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is about forgot password. The error facing is index out of range for this statement " If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then"

```
    Dim com As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    conn.Open()
    Dim query As String

    query = "select Password, CustomerName from userdetail where Email = @Email"

    com = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text)

    dr = com.ExecuteReader



    If dr(0).ToString > 0 Then

        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()

        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx")
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        e_mail = New MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress("xxx")
        e_mail.To.Add(Email.Text)
        e_mail.Subject = "Your Password Details"
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        e_mail.Body = "Hi, <br/>Please check your Login Detailss<br/><br/>Your Username: " &
                        Convert.ToString(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("CustomerName")) & "<br/><br/>Your Password: " &
                        Convert.ToString(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Password")) & "<br/><br/>"
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

    Else
        Label7.Text = "The Email you entered not exists"

    End
    conn.Close()
```

My database design:
UserId, Password, CustomerName, Contact, Email, Status

Comment: Then it would seem that `ds.Tables` is empty.  What is `ds` and where do you populate it?  It doesn't seem to be related in any way to your SQL interaction.  Also, you seem to be storing user passwords in plain text.  ***Never store user passwords in plain text.***  You're also emailing passwords to users.  ***Never email passwords.***  It's *grossly* irresponsible to your users.

Comment: Calling _If dr(0).ToString > 0 Then_  is meaningless and calling it after closing the connection and without any check if there are records will blow again and again. But still I don't understand where is the line that you say is throwing the exception. Surely not in the code posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you have changed the question and now you are mixed up between `MySqlDataReaders` and `DataSet`

the `MySqlDataReader` solution should look more like

```
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("YOURCONNECTIONSTRING")
        cn.Open()

        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select Password, CustomerName from userdetail where Email = @Email", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text)
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.Read() Then

                'Did find a record to access the fields use = dr("FieldName").ToString()


            Else

                'didnt find a record
            End If

            dr.Close()
            dr = Nothing

        End Using

    End Using
```

`Using` will take care of disposing the command and connection for you.

However I haven't tested this so emphasis the "look more like" and all this said David's comment is totally correct. Sending passwords in emails is never good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the `ds`, which I am assuming is a `Dataset`?..

```
Dim queryString As String = 
                "select Password, CustomerName from userdetail where Email = @Email"

Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text)
cmd.CommandText = queryString
da.SelectCommand = cmd
Dim ds As New DataSet()

conn.Open()
da.Fill(ds)
```

Then you can check your DataSet for the record.  You also need to make sure the following apply:

1. The `Email` field is **unique**
2. A link sent to the user to enable them to reset the password, and not send clear text.

Comment: And what is da in your code? :-) Note also that he/she works with MySql

Comment: @Steve, good spot - I only grabbed a portion of the c# code when converting, thx.

Comment: Thanks guys. Later i will implement password generated.